# What books do you recommend if I want to study complex numbers from scratch?

Tags: reference-request, complex-numbers, book-recommendation

I have studied calculus and linear algebra,but I still know little about complex numbers.

I intend to know a little about complex numbers at first, then I'll try to study functions of a complex variable

Comment: Do you wish to focus primarily on [complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) themselves, or also study functions of a complex variable?

Comment: @JW I intend to know a little about complex numbers at first,then I'll try to study functions of a complex variable.

Answer (score 2):

Check this lecture notes http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~mpd37/teaching/2015/145/notes_c_linalg.pdf

The first chapter should be enough for you.

The appendix of Linear Algebra by Friedberg also contains an introduction of complex numbers.

Comment: Thanks for recommendation.

Comment: Imperial college???? xDDD

Comment: Also very useful is chapter 5 in [**Elementary Linear Algebra**](http://www.numbertheory.org/book/) by Keith Matthews. Also, reasonably detailed solutions to all the exercises are given at this web page. Incidentally, I've been citing this on-line reference since 1997 or 1998, but not in a while, so I was quite surprised to see that it's still available.

Comment: @Masacroso is there anything wrong with it ?

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend this book:

Complex Variables: Introduction and Applications Second Edition (Cambridge Texts in Applied Mathematics) by Mark J. Ablowitz

Comment: Might be useful to tell the who the author is...

Comment: Good point @paulgarrett, I've added it now, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for recommendation.

Comment: A few words on why you highly recommend Ablowitz's book might also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Alfors: complex analysis is quite good and compact.

For a more detailed book try "Visual complex analysis".

Comment: Thanks for recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend H.A. Priestley *Introduction to Complex Analysis* (Oxford University Press).

It is easy to read and provides a great number of examples to every topic covered on the theory. The first chapter deals with complex numbers and algebra in the complex plane, and it is a concise introduction to develope the theory of complex analysis on one variable afterwards.

Also, one thing I really like from this book is that the author marks the most common mistakes made by students, so it warns you to not stumble on common pitfalls.

Comment: Thanks for recommendation.